# Windows 7 not genuine issue

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems

I have an HP mini 210 netbook which the OS is Windows 7 starter OEM. Yesterday, there was the pop up that said the Windows is not genuine anymore. As I remember before this thing happened, there's an update which is Windows update that prompted me there are updates for my computer.

My questions is:

- Do the OEM products have an expiry date?
- How do you reactivate the Windows / how do you retrieve the Windows product key?

Comment: Funny that you mentioned Windows Update but not the fact that you changed the hardware inside.

Comment: run MGADiag and post the log here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=52012

Comment: Did you try any of the WGA circumvention utilities?

Answer (score 3):

Are you *sure* the copy of Windows you are using is genuine? If yes, did you change any hardware? This could cause the operating system to think it's in a different computer and report it as pirated. [Here's a thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/made-a-hardware-change-now-windows-says-not/a9a44a40-5bf5-45d9-90a2-5d4f721a5f68) stating that changing the motherboard on an OEM is a violation of the agreement so in this situation it really wouldn't be genuine anymore.

Since the product key is encrypted and stored in the registry, you need a program to retrieve it. [Belarc](http://www.belarc.com/) or [Magical Jelly Bean Keyfinder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) can do it.

Comment: Yes, I've change the chipset because its burn due to overheating. I'll try to retrieve the key later. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very unusual. Be careful this isn't a fake validation attempt which could result in a virus or malware being installed on your computer. Do not click anything or enter any information on this popup window until you know for sure.

Update and run a complete scan with your antivirus software. Then run a malware scanner like [SUPERAntiSpyware](http://www.superantispyware.com/) or [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) (both are free).

Then to verify your Windows is Genuine, go to [Genuine Windows Validation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/exe-validation.aspx) and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, Windows license keys do not expire.
2. Your Windows is already activated. Microsoft is telling you that the
   key currently in use on the netbook is not valid. If you did not buy
   the netbook new, it's possible a key generator was used, and you'll
   have to buy a new, valid, key.

If you really want to try "re-activating", you can try re-entering the existing key in the `Windows Activation` dialog, most easily found on the `System Properties` dialog (I find to easiest to just right-click on the `Computer` link on the `Start Menu` and select `Properties` from the context menu).

The product key is found on the COA (Certificate of Authenticity) on the bottom of the netbook. If that is missing you could always try [Magical Jelly Bean](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/), but normally the OEM key used on the HP discs is not the same key as on the COA and will not activate manually.